# How to ignore unknown properties in jackson but not from parent java

Tags: jackson

I have two classes with inheritance. Parent class is in some other library and child has annotation @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)

What is happening is, all parent properties are ignored.

What I want, only unknown gets ignored but not from hierarchy or super classes.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with the issue for a while, and reading some misleading blogs I thought it was due to @JsonIgnoreProperties but in actual, issue was due to lombok @Jacksonized.

After removing @Jacksonized and adding @NoArgsConstrustor, problem is solved.